# Defining UICollectionViewCell with nib

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

If I understand correctly, the content of a [`UICollectionViewCell`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewCell_class/Reference/Reference.html) should go inside its `contentView` property and the background into `backgroundView`.

Yet, when I drag a `UICollectionViewCell` to Interface Builder there is no mention of `contentView` or `backgroundView`. If I add subviews, those will have the whole cell as its parent, not `contentView` or `backgroundView`.

What is the right way of defining a `UICollectionViewCell` with IB, then?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"If I add subviews, those will have the whole cell as its parent, not contentView"

This is not true. If you drag in a UICollectionViewCell, and add UI elements to it, you are adding them to the content view. The fact that it doesn't show up in the objects list doesn't mean it's not there (the same is true for NSBox - it has a content view that doesn't show up in IB either). If in collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:, you log cellForItemAtIndexPath, and look at its subviews, you find only one, and it's the same one you get by logging cell.contentView. If you log its subviews, then you will see your UI elements.

Now, as far as background view, I don't think that's something you can access from IB. You can have a xib file with a UIView, and then assign that to the cell's backgroundView property.

Comment: Half-true. I had tried this before and it didn't work. However, I had dragged a UIView and changed the type to a UICollectionViewCell subclass. It only works if you do exactly what you said: drag a UIColllectionViewCell from the library and then change the type. Very hacky.

Comment: @hpique, You do have to start with the correct type of object before you subclass it. By starting with the UICollectionViewCell, you get all its default properties and data, which you won't get with a UIView - there's nothing hacky about that.

Comment: It's bad because the `contentView` is implicit. Since I can't see it, I couldn't know without trial and error that starting with one type or the other makes a difference.

Comment: It *is* hacky, because if you create a nib file just for your cell (which is supported, via `[UICollectionView registerNib: forCellWithReuseIdentifier:]` the nib is created as a UIView by default. I can't work out how to get the contentView property to work, despite changing to the correct derived type.

Comment: Ignore that, I have to drag on the UICollectionViewCell, then delete the default UIView that it creates in order for this to work.

Comment: @MarkIngram, you can call it hacky if you want, but how is Xcode supposed to know that you want a UICollectionViewCell instead of a UIView when you create nib file? I guess they could add extra templates (or you could do that yourself) to do that, but it's easy enough to delete the default UIView, and drag out a UICollectionViewCell. I don't know why just changing the type doesn't work, that's just the way it is.

Comment: Thanks.  I had done the same - create a NIB for the collection view cell, then change the class of the Xcode-created view to my UICollectionViewCell subclass.  Then buttons didn't work.  Only after I deleted that view within the NIB and dragged in a UICollectionViewCell and changed its class to my subclass did buttons work.  This is totally non-obvious and a bad "gotcha" - I consider it a very bad violation of the principle of least surprise.  Thanks for the fix though!  :-)

Comment: I agree that this is bad Xcode design because UITableViewCells show the contentView.  There's no guessing there.  However they have chosen to follow a different pattern with UICollectionViewCells.

Answer (score 7):

For lack of a better option, I'm using separate nib files for the `contentView` and the `backgroundView`. Then in my `UICollectionViewCell` subclass:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        NSArray *contentViewNib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CollectionViewCellContentView" owner:self options:nil];
        [self.contentView addSubview:contentViewNib[0]];
        NSArray *backgroundViewNib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CollectionViewCellBackgroundView" owner:self options:nil];
        self.backgroundView = backgroundViewNib[0];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: so are you only registering your class with the collection view and then loading your xibs on initWithFrame of the cell class?

Comment: are you then able to access any outlets you may have set up on your xib through code?

Comment: doing it this way, as far as i can tell so far, is only good if you don't plan on changing any of the contents of those xibs. you wouldn't have dynamic content, labels or text fields that change per cell in those xibs would you?

Comment: Spot on with the [self.contentView addSubview:contentViewNib[0]]; Nice one!

Comment: @tote Why can't it be dynamic? I am running into the problem you mentioned; all my IBOutlet is nil if I use this approach.

Comment: In the nib set the owner to the custom cell.  After that you can all the outlets for the custom cell to the various elements in the nib.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is new to Xcode 8 but `UICollectionViewCell` includes outlets for connecting the `backgroundView` and `selectedBackgroundView`.

[image]

Thanks to this, you can add a `UIView` (or subclass) to your collection view cell and connect it to either one of the outlets. This way you'll be able to define them using IB.

[image]

Hope this helps!