# Loading a nib into a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm just starting to use the UICollectionView so bear with me!

How do I load a nib into the cell?

It seems I have to register the nib and class to be used, but this does not work.

Code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [collectionView registerClass:[CluelessSymbolCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Symbol cell"];
    [collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CluelessSymbolCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]  forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Symbol cell"];

    CluelessSymbolCell *cell = (CluelessSymbolCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Symbol cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    CluelessClue *clue = [clueManager clueForIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.backgroundImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[clue.imageNames objectAtIndex:0]]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: i'm not sure you can register both a nib and a class. you can register a cell class and load a nib as part of its view in the initWithFrame initializer like http://stackoverflow.com/a/13419962/62068 (but i'm not sure if you'll have programmatic access to the outlets defined in the xib by name...) or you can load a xib that you linked to a class, but then the initWithFrame initializer isn`t invoked

Answer (score 1):

It turns out my nib file had the default view controller in it (which was hidden) as well as my custom cell - doh!