# UITableView inside UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to have UITableView inside my UICollectionViewCell. I would then dynamically change the content of UITableView through the subclass of UICollectionViewCell.

My subclass of UICollectionViewCell .h looks like this:

```
@interface ShopCollectionCell : UICollectionViewCell <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end
```

in .m is just standard UITableView methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 3;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"bla"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"bla"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"test";
    return cell;
}
```

in my UIViewController I have a UICollectionView where I do the following:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ShopCollectionCell *cell = (ShopCollectionCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"shopDetailCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ShopCollectionCell alloc] init];//:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.myLabel.text = @"test";

    return cell;
}
```

I don't understand why I am getting zombie object ?!

[image]

Comment: declare tableView as strong and check...hope this solves

Comment: @AUK4SO adding UITableView as strong didn't help. Still getting the same zombie object

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath` you need to also register a class or a nib for that cell identifier.

in your viewDidLoad, you should use either of the two **UITableView** methods below to register a cell

```
registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:
registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:
```

Check out the [UITableView docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerNib%3aforCellReuseIdentifier%3a) for further details on how to use them

You should then be able to delete the following lines completely:

```
   if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ShopCollectionCell alloc] init];//:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
The error message you posted to me made it pretty easy to figure out what was wrong.
You load the NIB with "self" as owner, but then you replace self with the first view loaded from the NIB. I would use a UIView as rootview in your NIB, and add that loaded view into the cell's contentView property.

Comment: That's exactly what I do in my subclass of UIViewController - I register my subclass of UICollectionViewCell. See ppdevelopment.cz/ios/JSTest.zip

Comment: Ah, I didn't see your zip file. The project in the zip file doesn't work though. It gives me the following error: "the item height must be less that the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values.". I'm still at work, so I can't dig too deep here :)

Comment: that's quite weird I get "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM numberOfSectionsInTableView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d93d10'" but when I remove the datasource and delegate of the UITableView inside the ShopCollCell.xib it doesn't crash, but doesn't provide anything into tableview obviously

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean in your updated answer, could you post a sample?

Comment: I guess this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13419962/975813 is kinda similar to what you suggest. However, that way I cannot access IBOutlets

Comment: Spot on! Sorry for the lack of details, but I'm crunching at work these days :)

Comment: Just uploaded version 2 (http://ppdevelopment.cz/ios/JSTest-v2.zip) with fix from http://stackoverflow.com/a/13419962/975813. Now I lack the access to my IBOutlets, so that self.myLabel is nil when setupMyLabel method is invoked :-/! Thanks a lot for helping me out

Comment: Try removing NSArray *backgroundViewNib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ShopCollCell" owner:self options:nil];
        self.backgroundView = backgroundViewNib[0];

Comment: Nope, no difference at all

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove alloc and init of collection view cell. 
dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier is must be enough.
From apple documentation:

> This method dequeues an existing cell if one is available or creates a new one based on the class or nib file you previously registered.

Comment: I thought about it as well, but nope it doesn't help either

Comment: I uploaded the project here http://ppdevelopment.cz/ios/JSTest.zip if you would be interested in cracking on it

Answer (score 0):

Making following 3 changes worked for me.

1. In ShopCollCell.xib, map tableView delegate and datasource to `ShopCollectionCell` class and not to File's owner.
2. In ShopCollectionCell.m implement `initWithCoder:` method.
3. In ShopCollectionCell.m implement `awakeFromNib` method and register `UITableViewCell` class for the `mytableView` here.

   ```
   - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
       if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {

       }

       return self;
   }


   - (void)awakeFromNib {
       [self.myTableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"bla"];
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it seems to work similar to this solution  (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13419962/975813). However, the problem is that I cannot access the IBOutlets now (self.myLabel is nil). See http://ppdevelopment.cz/ios/JSTest-v2.zip